# How do I make something light sensitive?

Tags: game-engine, lighting

Say I I’m shining a flashlight (spotlight parented with camera) at something, how do I make that something react a certain way. (Ie. what sensor do I need to use for an object to be able to detect light?)

Any simple tips would help, just a beginner here.

Answer (score 2):

For the light itself you can't, but you can fake it using a physics object with the light shape and detecting this object through collision. The file below is a working example, and contains the instructions below on the Text Editor for convenience.

Use the Outliner to click the described object and check the given properties.

## Project Structure

- Scene '_lib_props':

  - 'player' objects in the first layer, all added to the group 'player'.
  - 'box' objects in the second layer, all added to the group 'box'.
- Scene 'scenery':

  - 'ground' and 'walls' are mesh objects.
  - The 'player' is a group instance of the group 'player' from the lib scene.
  - The 'boxes' are group instances of the group 'box' from the lib scene.

## Player Structure

Check the Outliner for a better overview of the structure of the player.

- Object 'flashlight_lamp_collision' is a mesh object parented to 'flashlight_lamp', and it contains the following properties:

  - Property 'flashlight' to be detected by the boxes.
  - Physics type Static, Ghost enabled, Invisible enabled, Collision Bounds set to Triangle Mesh.

With these options, this object can be detected by the 'box_sensor' objects.

## Box Structure

Check the Outliner for a better overview of the structure of the box.

- Object 'box_visual' is a mesh object parented to 'box_sensor', and it contains the following properties:

  - Physics type Static, Collision Bounds set to Triangle Mesh.
  - Object 'box_sensor' is a mesh object, and it contains the following properties:
  - Physics type Sensor, Invisible enabled, Collision Bounds set to Triangle Mesh.

With these options, this object can detect the player's 'flashlight_lamp_collision' using a collision sensor.

[image]